# NSString doesn’t understand the “stringWithString_” message

Tags: applescript

I'm creating an AppleScript Script Library, and want to call some Cocoa methods on NSString. I created an .SCPTD file with this method:

```
on xtrim(sourceText)
    set the sourceString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:sourceText

    set whitespace to {space, tab, return, linefeed}
    set the adjustedString to sourceString's stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(whitespace)

    return (adjustedString as string)
end xtrim
```

However, I get the error `NSString doesn’t understand the “stringWithString_” message.`. Most answers I find on the internet suggest that the AppleScript/Objective-C Library checkbox is not checked.

However, this checkbox has been [removed with the Yosemite release](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_10/RN-10_10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000982-CH110-SW13).

What is wrong with the script; is there a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from an [Apple thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/48927?answerId=144472022#144472022):

> As of Yosemite, ASObjC is available everywhere, not just libraries and applications.  Importing the desired terminology via the `use` statement is now directly supported in the Script Editor - for your example, the `NSString class` stuff is available by adding a `use framework "Foundation"` statement.